# Write IplImage to .avi file, using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

What i'm trying to do is to capture frames from a webcam (on the server side), and send them over a socket (using Qt) and save them to an .avi file on the client side.

I managed to grab frames from the webcam (using OpenCV) on the server side, i had to convert from IplImage to QImage (so i can send images over QTcpSocket). On the client side, i receive the QImage, convert it back to IplImage so i can write the received frames to .avi file.

The problem is that, i can't write the received frames (which were previously converted to IplImage) to .avi file. I don't get any error when i build the project or when running the project. The .avi file is created, but is empty. And i managed to dispaly the IplImages using cvShowImage().

For writing the frames to .avi (on the client side), i used cvWriteFrame().

I used Qt Creator 2.4.1, with OpenCV library 2.4.2, on 32bit windows7.

Comment: What is the FourCC you are specifying for the `CvVideoWriter` object you are creating? Also make sure the video name is without any spaces and like `video001.avi`. The numbers at the end are necessary when specifying the name for OpenCV video.

Comment: I used FLV1, the same i used on the server side (i had to save frames to .avi on the server side too) and it works ok.